# Fintiely Generated Modules Over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated, module-isomorphism

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a principal Ideal domain
>   $R$. Show that  there exists an $R$-module homomorphism $f:
>  R^m\rightarrow R^n$ such that $M\simeq \frac{R^n}{\operatorname{Im}(f)}$, where
>   $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ denotes the image of $f$.

Can anyone help me to write its proof? I have no ideas about it.

Comment: I have received two very good answers to this question @ThorWittich,LordSharktheUnknown. The acceptance of the answer is based on that ThorWittich clarified my doubts in comments on answers but other one left for me to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify: You are supposed to show the existence of two natural numbers $n$ and $m$ together with a map $f \colon R^m \rightarrow R^n$ such that $M \cong R^n/\text{im}(f)$. What we will show is, that $n$ can be taken as the number of generators of $M$ (works as $M$ is finitely generated) and $m$ can be taken as the number of generators of the image of $f$ (in particular we need to argue that this image is free).

Since $M$ is finitely generated, say by $n$ elements, we have a surjection $g \colon R^n \rightarrow M$ and therefore we get $M \cong R^n/\text{ker}(g)$. Now the kernel is a submodule of a free module over a pid and therefore free of say rank $m$. Thus there is a morphism $f \colon R^m \rightarrow R^n$ given by the composition of the isomorphism of the kernel to $R^m$ and the inclusion $i \colon \text{ker}(g) \rightarrow R^n$, such that $M \cong R^n/\text{im}(f)$.

Comment: If $M$ was generated by more than $n$ elements, Then?

Comment: Submodules of free modules over a pid are always free. We do not need the assumption of being finitely generated for that.

Comment: True, But My Question is that what if $M$ was generated by $n+1$ elements? My point of confusion is that you have taken the same number as the number of copies of $R$ in $g$.

Comment: Why would that matter? Let $n+1 = r$ and do the same proof. The number $n$ is arbitrary. The exercise demands to show the existence of two numbers  $n,m$ such that ...

Comment: In the last statement, you say "*the inclusion*", but I didn't get which inclusion map are you talking about?

Comment: Made it more precise. I meant the inclusion from the kernel into $R^n$.

Comment: I think it will be $i:$ ker$(g)\rightarrow R^n$.?

Comment: Yes, was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

As $M$ is finitely generated, there's some surjection $g:R^n\to M$.

Let $K$ be the kernel of $g$, so $M\cong R^n/K$.

As $R$ is a PID it is Noetherian.

A submodule of a f.g. module over a Noetherian ring is f.g.

Then $K$ is f.g., and there's some surjection $h:R^m\to K$.

Let $f=i\circ h$ where $i:K\to R^n$ is the inclusion.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the fact that a submodule of a f.g. free module over a PID is free?

Comment: Here, presumably, you have taken that $M$ cannot be generated by more than $n$ elements, but what if it is generated by more than $n$ elements say $n+1$. Then, will $g$ be surjective?